# VW oil cooler was leaking

Tags: oil

my 2003 vw tdi oil cooler was leaking oil,i had the O ring replaced and after a week,it started to leak again.The mechanic said nothing more could be done,but now it has stopped leaking completely??? i'm confused,what does this mean?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Usually when replacing an O-ring I'd smear a small amount of clean engine oil on it so it wasn't going in dry.  It's possible that your mechanic omitted this step and installed it dry.

The other possibility is that the oil you were seeing was just a little residual oil left over from when it had been leaking.

Comment: thank you that seems entirely plausible but it did leak for a few weeks prior to stopping

Comment: It may be possible your mechanic had put a little too much oil when topping it up which could have caused too much pressure on the dry o-ring. 
I guess the tiny leak properly soaked the seal and the oil level came back to normal pressure.